# How to cross compile mono for x86 android

Tags: c#, android, android-ndk, mono

I have tried many different ways.  I completed a compile with the NDK and when I run it on an emulator with the adp shell, I get no output.

mono-3.10.0 from a tarball

Here are my environment variables:

```
export CC=i686-linux-android-gcc
export SYSROOT=/home/XXUSERNAMEXX/Develop/android-ndk-r10d/platform/android-17/arch-x86
export PATH=/tmp/my-android-toolchain/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Here is my configure:

```
 ./configure --disable-mcs-build --host=i686-linux-android --prefix=/home/XXUSERNAMEXX/vmshare/workspace/HelloJni/jni/mono-2.0 --target=i686-linux-android --build=i686-linux-gnu
```

then just
    make
then
    make install

Then build a C# sample of just:
    // HelloAndroid.cs
    // Outputs HelloAndroid.exe
    using System;

```
namespace HelloAndroid
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

then I copy
mono-sgen
libmonosgen-2.0.so
HelloAndroid.exe 
to an android directory of

```
/data/data/com.example.helloandroid
```

change all the permissions to 755
change all the ownerships to system:system

then type

./mono-sgen HelloAndroid.exe

in the adp shell

then I just get nothing.
no errors, no output, just the command line returns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compile the .NET Assemblies (System.dll ...) like for regular host and to put them into Android.

In addition define `MONO_PATH` to mono runtimes.